# how can i play two video on one screen?

Tags: android, video, android-video-player

i have to make an application where i need to play two video simultaniously,on screen.
here is my code.but the video dose not play.am i doing wrong anywhere? :(

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.start();
    VideoView myVideoView2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview2);
    myVideoView2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath2));

    myVideoView2.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView2.requestFocus();
    myVideoView2.start();
    }
```

Comment: you can go with the fragment.

Comment: Which layout you are using ? How myVideoView and ,myVideoView2 are placed on screen ? please provide more information....

Comment: please provide some more useful information so that we can find out a solution

Comment: @rahul i use linearlayout where videoview insided

Comment: are both the video views are visible to you ?...

Comment: check this example: [**Dual VideoView to play 3gp from YouTube**](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/03/dual-videoview-to-play-3gp-from-youtube.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you require two separate threads for playing two videos. since IO operations are blocking... One of the video Player may starve for CPU... Call start() in two separate threads.... Hope that helps!!!

**EDIT**
first remove the start() calls from onCreate().. Create two separate threads

```
    Thread view1Thrad = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
    myVideoView.start();
    });
    Thread view2Thrad = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
        myVideoView2.start();
        });
```

now start these threads one by one...

```
view1Thread.start(); //starts first video
view2Thread.start(); //starts second video
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: how can i attach and where  need to use thread.show me please

Comment: thanx a lot helping me to fix this :)

Comment: has there any connection of high resulation video?i think high resulation videos doesnot play simultaniously.is there any way to reduce their resulation programatiaclly?

Comment: From where you are reading the videofile ? Changing the video resolution programmatically will take lots of time and may be your phone will hang...