# How to show same video in two VideoViews simultaneously

Tags: android, multithreading, android-videoview, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm working with VideoView and I'm trying to show same video in two Videoviews like this  [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mobius.vrcinema)

I'm following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023605/how-can-i-play-two-video-on-one-screen) to show the video in two VideoViews but I'm getting delay in both audio and video on both videoviews so please help me to solve this problem. I need to play the video at the same time without any delay

Thank you..

Comment: use TextureView...instead of videoview

Comment: Use fragments to achieve this. I tried I am able to that.

Comment: with TextureView also getting delay..

Comment: If I used fragments then little bit delay is occurring for two video players..

Answer (score 0):

Two TextureViews and two MediaPlayers should do the trick. Here's is a [link](http://www.malmstein.com/blog/2014/08/09/how-to-use-a-textureview-to-display-a-video-with-custom-media-player-controls/) for a demo of video playing with TextureView.

http://www.malmstein.com/blog/2014/08/09/how-to-use-a-textureview-to-display-a-video-with-custom-media-player-controls/

Then you can play video with sync by managing two media players. If you face problems while playing in sync comment on this answer and I'll post code.

Answer (score 0):

The code example in this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-bdk0k_XXE) shows two `VideoView`s playing near the end of the clip. The example is playing different videos, but you can set the URL of each `VideoView` to the same video.